# enzyme testing react with context api

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test a form. When the form is submitted it should set a state on `error: true` and then a `div` with an error information should appear. My test looks like this:

```
 outer = shallow(<Search />);

 it("should not submit a form and display an error if title or author is empty", () => {
    const Children = outer.props().children({});
    const wrapper = mount(Children);
    const button = wrapper.find("form button");
    button.simulate("submit", {
      preventDefault() {
        outer.setState({ error: true });
      }
    });
    expect(wrapper.find("div.error")).toHaveLength(1);
  });
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. I am new to unit testing and I have no idea if I'm doing it correctly and how should I fix that.

I think I also should get somehow inputs values but don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

This is the sample to set value to input elements:

```
it('Should capture firstname correctly onChange', function(){
    const component = mount(<Form />);
    const input = component.find('input').at(0);
    input.instance().value = 'hello';
    input.simulate('change');
    expect(component.state().firstname).toEqual('hello');
})
```

But it may not work because of different other reasons, make sure you have initialized enzyme components in `beforeAll()`. Try to read enzyme's examples about this topic.